# sawtooth generator wave simple. java

Tags: java, javasound

i'm trying to make the simplest code (less than 3 or 4 lines) to generate a  sawtooth wave in java

I already know the period,frequency, and amplitude of the graph (2). Any suggestions appreciated. I know that i need to use mod arithmetic with the period

i know i need to map the values of [0, period -1] to [-1, 1]. Idk how to use this with modulo arithmetic.

Comment: Please indicate your programmation language, and maybe a proposal for your algorithme that the community may comment and improve. Question with code get more and better answers.

Comment: How will you use this algorithme, for which purpose, and how will it be called ?

Comment: Maybe start from this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/740619/noise-in-background-when-generating-sine-wave-in-java?rq=1

Comment: Define exactly what you mean by "generate". Exactly what is the "output" you want?

Answer (score 0):

**

### You can try this [project](https://github.com/billthefarmer/sig-gen) it have sample for sine,squre and saw waveform.

**
[image]